# Button subclass with Alpha

Tags: android

I'm trying to set the transparency of a button using the API level 10 (so no view.setAlpha).
I wrapped the `Button.onDraw` calling a `Canvas.saveLayerAlpha` on a subclass: this works with the text but not with the button background.

I want to make it possible to leave the current button's background management, should I draw the button background myself without calling `super.onDraw`? How to get a consistent reference to the current button background inside the `onDraw` extent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do what you're doing but override draw() instead of onDraw().

Comment: I found it usefull to get the background, mutate it, setting alpha ant and assing the background back. what the differences are?

Comment: Doing so will not give you the proper result. The content of your onDraw() method will be blended with the already blended background. You should instead override draw(). It's also easier than mutating the background.